# Matching columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to check if certain processes or values (column c) match a master list (column a).

I have a rule set up and it highlights the matches in the master list column and fills it green.

The master list contains duplicates. So two rows will have the same data. For example. a1=str123 and a4=str123.

When using the Match command, it turns both cells in column a (a1 & a4) green. This occurs even if the match column only contains one instance of the data (c5=str123).

I am looking for a way to do a Match but the master list to only turn a cell green if there is one instance of it and then ignore the match that occurred when checking for matches for another cell.

Basically I am looking for a way to setup matching between two cells but once one match has been found to ignore it when going through the rest of the list.

Comment: Show the work you've done so far.

Comment: The simplest way would be using Excel "Remove duplicates" feature on "master" Column A and then apply VLOOKUP or whatever you are using: this will solve the problem. Best regards,

Comment: If you can show us a sample from the table that would help a lot.. do you just need the unique values from column A that have matches or do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by conditional formatting using two match formulas. I assume you have a fixed set of master values in column a, say in cells A2:A6. I will assume you have values to test if they exist in column C, say in C2:C6 and other columns are blank. In column B enter numbers 1..5 in B2..B6 as an index to the master values. In column D enter the formula `=MATCH(C2,$A$2:$A$6,0)` in D2 and copy down. In column E enter the formula `=MATCH(B2,$D$2:$D$6,0)` in E2 and copy down. Select the master range A2:A6 and choose conditional formatting, using the formula `=ISNUMBER($E2)` and format green fill or whatever you want. With this combination the formulas in column D find the first matching master item, and formula in col E tests to see if the index in col B is in the list of matches in col D.

Comment: This is the closest answer I have gotten but the main problem is still occurring.

Comment: The problem is that some values are doubles in the master column. When I compare them to the match list if there are two instances of the double job it ignores the second occurrence of it.